# Webcam not found on Thinkpad E550 (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: webcam, thinkpad, input-devices

I got a new laptop Thinkpad E550 and at first the touchpad was not working so I updated the kernel but now the webcam is not working.
Cheese is giving the error "device not found"

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055a Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `lsusb` in your terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t), and paste the result back here by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/662934/edit) your question?

Comment: ➜  ~  lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055a Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
➜  ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug for your webcam, it seems that it's not supported yet:
[Acer, Inc ID 5986:055a is useless after 14.04.2 installed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1433906)

Please subscribe to that bug to get you updated.
Also, you can click on the **This bug affects # people. Does this bug affect you?** string to state that you're affected by this as well.

Or you can patch it by yourself with a patch (ignore_chining_errors.patch) provided in:
http://sourceforge.net/p/linux-uvc/mailman/message/34182460/

By following instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to build your own kernel.

Comment: I subscribed to the bug, but I dont know how to patch it and fix it(if thats what you meant)
Can we download this version of ubuntu, this shows that webcam will work http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201411-16167/

Comment: No, the camera for that pre-installed ThinkPad Edge E550 is "CHICONY Electronics Co Ltd Integrated Camera", which is different from yours.

Comment: @sarthakagarwal This issue is now fixed in Xenial / Yakkety -proposed kernel, it should be available in updates two weeks later!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem with cheese. So, I've installed **GTK UVC Video Viewer** and its features are also good.

You can install it via terminal by using this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pj-assis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0
```

Solved my issue.

I was getting device not found in Cheese.
Checked the camera with vlc using

```
cvlc v4l2:// :input-slave=alsa:// :v4l-vdev="/dev/video0"
```

It was giving the error

```
v4l2 demux error: cannot open device '/dev/video0': Permission denied
```