# Built-in webcam not working on Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad E450

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, webcam, thinkpad

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad E450. The system can't see the webcam, it's not found when I turn on Cheese or Skype, neither when I try to list it using `lsusb`.
It works fine on Windows 10. I'm sure that button on keyboard that enables webcam is turned on, I pressed it few times at it's still not listed.

Do you have any idea what is the reason?

Thank you from advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem. You might want to checkout this
http://askubuntu.com/questions/662934/webcam-not-found-on-thinkpad-e550-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: If you're using 5986:055a Acer webcam, this [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1433906) is now fixed in Xenial -proposed kernel, if the verification task went well, it should be available in updates about two weeks later. Please upgrade your system to Xenial or upgrade the kernel to 4.4